# Extract time from a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a column like **`last_located_time`** which contain values like 
**`2017-05-13T17:33:36.000+0000`**.

I have tried to remove only time, but no luck.

```
SELECT USERNAME, TO_DATE(SUBSTR(LAST_LOCATED_TIME,11,17),'HH:MI:SS') "lAST TIME"
FROM Tb_089
```

How should I extract only time value from the columns for all users?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the type of the column?

Comment: `to_char(last_located_time, 'hh24:mi:ss')`

Answer (score 2):

If you want the time component in the UTC time zone (so all times are being displayed in a common time zone) then:

*(assuming you have a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type)*

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         last_located_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
         'HH24:MI:SS'
       )
FROM   Tb_089;
```

If you, instead, the column is an ISO 8601 formatted string:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
           last_located_time,
           'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZHTZM'
         ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
         'HH24:MI:SS'
       )
FROM   Tb_089;
```

If you want the time component as an interval:

```
SELECT CAST( utc_last_located_time AS TIMESTAMP ) - TRUNC( utc_last_located_time )
         AS time_interval
FROM   (
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
           last_located_time,
           'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZHTZM'
         ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utc_last_located_time
  FROM   Tb_089
);
```

If you want the time component of the string (without adjusting for disparate time zones) then you could just do:

```
SELECT SUBSTR( last_located_time, 12, 8 )
FROM   Tb_089
```

Comment: thanks it worked the date is in ISO8601 format... Is there a way to find if the datetime stamp is in ISO format or with time zone...?

Comment: @VBAToddler [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC) includes `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`, `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ` (indicating zero UTC offset), `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+HH` and `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+HH:MM` (or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+HHMM`) and they will all be parsed by the format model `'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZHTZM'`. The [`TZH` and `TZM` format elements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#sthref416) is included to parse those [optional] time zone components.

Answer (score 0):

`To_Date` is used to convert Char and Varchar2 into Date.

You need to use `To_Char` which is opposite of To_Date

```
Select To_Char(LAST_LOCATED_TIME, 'HH24:MI:SS') "Last Time" from Tb_089;
```

Comment: I already tried but it is giving error ORA-01722: invalid number